# Fantasy book where two boys swap places from different worlds

Tags: story-identification, magic, parallel-universe

I am looking for a book I read when I was younger. It involves 2 boys from different world swapping places and pretending to be each other. They are identical except that one is white and the other is red, and when they swap places, they change colour except for the area around the groin/arse area. This stays the colour of their home world. The boy from this world also had been speaking what he thought was a made up language for years before he even met his "twin", and it turns out it's the language from the other world.
There is also a scene where in the other world he discovers the sun actually travels through a tunnel in the earth when it sets, taking it back to where it can rise again.
At some point they discover that their fathers, also identical, had at some point done the same as them.

Comment: Can you give an approximate year or set of years when you read this book? Do you remember anything about the cover? was it aimed at a particular age group?

Comment: It was in our junior library, and I think aimed at slightly older kids. So young teenager demographic I think. And I read it in the 90's